# Is it possible to create a GCM API key after app installation?

Tags: android, security, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way in which I can create an API key *per app installation*, so I can expose the API key to the user and let them send notifications to the app?

If I have a single API key for the app and expose it, [users may send notifications to topics (which may then result in notifications being shown to other users) and the API key might be throttled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901752/is-it-inherently-dangerous-to-expose-make-public-my-api-key-for-gcm#comment59547515_35901752)

I would like to the user of the app to be able to send notifications to his own app (by using the GCM API) but not to any apps installed on other devices. It seems that the safest way would be if I could give each user a separate API key, because their use of the API would only have consequences for themselves.

Comment: why not just create some unique key for the user and then append that to the topic name? that would result in the same effect

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I want anyone to be able to send notifications to the app through the GCM API (without going through any backend service I might provide). I am pretty sure that means I need to expose an API key, one way or another.

Comment: wait are you saying you want the user to send a GCM message from the app itself vs a server sending it?

Comment: No, I want the user to send their own notifications through the GCM API. Not using the app. The app only receives notifications. --- I know this is a peculiar use case, but trust me it makes sense :-P

Comment: topics are not shared across apps, if app A has a topic `cars` and app B has a topic `cars` then app A sends an update to a server or something and that triggers a GCm message to the `cars` topic only people subscribes to the topic in app A will get that push. App B knows nothing about that topic. unless I am misunderstanding what you are tryign to do

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I want to do :) I want to do what I say: have a *single* app that gets a *different* API key with every installation. So when user A installs it, it gets API key x; when user B installs it, it gets API key y.

Comment: well no I get that part but what I am getting at is that its not possible to do that so I am offering other suggestions that would do the same that you want to create by doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple API keys in the same project, misbehaviour by one API key holder would negatively affect all API key holders.

Seems like you need each of your users to have their own Google Developer Project, Sender ID and API key. Then have their app generate InstanceID tokens using the corresponding SenderID. A single app can register with multiple Sender IDs. That way each sender would be responsible for their own activities.

Comment: Great! Sounds like it *is* possible. I am missing a note on exactly *how* I can do that, though. What would I need the users to provide? Just a Sender ID? I guess I can see how that could work ...